# Rails /lib modules and

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module

I am writing a custom wrapper for `open_flash_chart` plugin. It's placed in `/lib` and load it as a module in `ApplicationController`.

However, I have either a problem with the Class hierarchy or some other problem.

From any controller I can access `open_flash_chart` functions as `OpenFlashChart`, `Line` etc.

However, in a class in a `/lib` module, it doesnt work!

Any ideas?

Comment: hope this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304110/is-it-possible-to-include-modules-in-rake-task-and-make-its-methods-available-fo/54250302#54250302

Answer (score 149, accepted):

There are two ways that files get loaded in Rails:

- It is registered in the autoload process, and you reference a constant that corresponds to the file name. For instance, if you have `app/controllers/pages_controller.rb` and reference PagesController, `app/controllers/pages_controller.rb` will automatically be loaded. This happens for a preset list of directories in the load path. This is a feature of Rails, and is not part of the normal Ruby load process.
- Files are explicitly `require`d. If a file is `require`d, Ruby looks through the entire list of paths in your load paths, and find the first case where the file you `require`d is in the load path. You can see the entire load path by inspecting $LOAD_PATH (an alias for $:).

Since `lib` is in your load path, you have two options: either name your files with the same names as the constants, so Rails will automatically pick them up when you reference the constant in question, or explicitly require the module.

I also notice that you might be confused about another thing. ApplicationController is **not** the root object in the system. Observe:

```
module MyModule
  def im_awesome
    puts "#{self} is so awesome"
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include MyModule
end

class AnotherClass
end

AnotherClass.new.im_awesome
# NoMethodError: undefined method `im_awesome' for #<AnotherClass:0x101208ad0>
```

You will need to include the module into whatever class you want to use it in.

```
class AnotherClass
  include MyModule
end

AnotherClass.new.im_awesome
# AnotherClass is so awesome
```

Of course, in order to be able to include the module in the first place, you'll need to have it available (using either of the techniques above).

Comment: Just wanted to add : If one of your module in /lib (or in one of the autoload directories) is already define ; exemple you overload ActiveRecord or String, you'll have to explicitly require it or it won't be loaded

Comment: strangely, I'm getting: uninitialized constant GaClient (NameError), unless I require 'ga_client' beforehand (the class is defined in lib/ga_client.rb). Is there documentation for the autoload naming scheme?

Answer (score 88):

In Rails 3 /lib modules are not loaded automatically.

This is because the line:

```
# config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
```

inside config/application.rb is commented.

You can try to uncomment this line or, (it worked even better for me), leave this commented (for future reference) and add this two lines:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Comment: This will duplicate `../lib` path in `ApplicationName::Application.config.autoload_paths` array.

Comment: @jibiel so what's the resolution here?

Comment: why did the latter option work better for you?  Also, why was the default changed...there must be a reason despite lots of people finding work arounds.

Comment: @ylluminate So single `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]` should be enough.

@ckarbass Second line gives you the freedom to organize your utilities into _subfolders_ and thus niftify your modules with _namespaces_. That's pretty much it. And [here's why](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5218#ticket-5218-7) the default was changed.

Better late than never :)

Comment: This seems a bit messy to me. Wouldn't this unnecessarily auto-load rake tasks?

Answer (score 25):

What worked for me, besides uncommenting config.autoload_paths (I’m on Rails 3.1.3), was to create a initializer like this:

```
#config/initializers/myapp_init.rb
require 'my_module'    
include MyModule
```

This way I can call mymodule methods **from anywhere** and as class methods `Model.mymodule_method` or as instance methods `mymodel.mymodule_method`

Maybe some expert may explain the implications of this. By now, use it at your own risk.

**Edit:** Afterwards, I think a better approuch would be:

create a initializer like this:

```
#config/initializers/myapp_init.rb
require ‘my_module’
```

Include the module where needed, like this:

1) if you want to use it as "Class Methods" use "extend":

```
class Myclass < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend MyModule
   def self.method1
      Myclass.my_module_method
   end
end
```

2) if you want to use it as "Instance Methods" include it inside Class definition:

```
class Myclass < ActiveRecord::Base
include MyModule
   def method1
      self.my_module_method 
   end
end
```

3) remember that `include MyModule` refers to a file `my_module.rb` in your load path that must be required first

Comment: I have created my module on `lib` folder, therefore i have added `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` on `config/application.rb` file. After that i followed your suggestion to adding `config/initializers/myapp_init.rb` file and it's contents. Everything is good. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Even though `require` works for me and auto-loading does not (undefined module method), [this comment says you shouldn't use `require`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3#comment3541227_3376401).

Answer (score 3):

To use the module `lib/my_module.rb` in your models and controllers:

In `config/application.rb`:

```
config.watchable_dirs['lib'] = [:rb]
```

In your model (similar idea for your controller):

```
require_dependency 'my_module'

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModule

  MyModule.some_method
end
```

This method is described in more detail at http://hakunin.com/rails3-load-paths

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that you want to explicitly load file(s) under lib directory at time of application initialization. 
 In my config/application.rb, I have an entry as, 
 `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` 
 
 Also this might be the case that module name/hierarchy is not same as it is in file or location/name of file is not same as that hierarchy, so auto-load of that file is also not possible. So when I added an entry at bottom of config/application.rb as, 
 `require "./lib/file_name_without_extention`  
 it worked fine.