# How can I force my plugin to reload with each request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, ruby-on-rails-plugins, reload

As I understand it, plugins are not reloaded in Rails with each request in development mode.
Which makes sense, as generally you add plugins to your app and it's the app you're developing.

But if you are developing a plugin, you have to restart the server with each change to the plugin which has a significant overhead.

Is there any way to make Rails reload your plugin during development, the way it reloads your models and controllers?

Comment: Having the same problem. The current answers are either not acceptable for me or they don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If restarting the server automatically when plugin code changes is an acceptable solution, you could use Mike Clark/topfunky's [`rstakeout`](http://svn.topfunky.com/public/scripts/rstakeout.rb) for that, or the newer [`watchr`](https://github.com/mynyml/watchr) which sounds like it does the same thing.

You would do something like this:

```
rstakeout 'touch tmp/restart.txt' 'vendor/plugins/**/*'
```

Comment: Guard is also a good solution to watching files for changes. The guard-passenger plugin restarts the server when files change: https://github.com/mordaroso/guard-passenger

Answer (score 10):

I have been struggling with this for some time, too. None of the solutions work, including the `autoload_paths` and `autoload_once_paths` tricks. Furthermore, the hack with `FileUpdateChecker` and initializers also does not help (the checker triggers properly, but the files are not reloaded). Same for `config.reload_plugins = true`...

However, there is a solution. In `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` add one line:
`require_dependency 'your_file_name_here'`
The application controller **is** reloaded on every request and `require_dependency` makes your file to be checked for modifications and reloaded accordingly. It worked for me, Apache 2, Passenger 3 and Rails 3.0.3.

Comment: On a second pass, config.reload_plugins = true is working for me.

Comment: require_dependency worked for me.  In addition, as my plugin requires its own files in turn, I had to replace those require statements with require_dependency...

Comment: I suspect reload_plugins didn't work because presumably I have the files set up wrong, and they don't get loaded by rails automatically, requiring instead a manual 'require' statement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073076/rails-lib-modules-and

Comment: In `application.rb` instead than on controller: `ActionDispatch::Reloader.to_prepare{ require_dependency 'your_file' }`

Comment: I only got this to work when _also_ adding the lib-dir to autoload paths. That is: in `test/dummy/config/application.rb` inside the `class Application < Rails::Application do`-block add: `config.autoload_paths += %W{ #{Rails.root.join('../../lib/')} }`

Answer (score 3):

I do this by using the shotgun gem.

`gem install shotgun`

`cd /path/to/rails/app`

`shotgun`

slower response time, but reloading all the rails code, not wasting time to write autoload_paths

Comment: My gosh, this is amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way, develop your plugin in a folder inside the *"app"* folder:

- app

  - models
  - controllers
  - helpers
  - views
  - **your_plugin_here**

This way, all your plugin classes will be reloaded on each request.

Another possibility is to add the path at your application.rb file:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)

module SunspotTutorial
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.autoload_paths += %W{ #{config.root}/plugins/your_plugin_name/lib }

    #lots of other code
  end
end
```

This way your plugin is going to be reloaded all the time.

Comment: thats what I've resorted to but it doesn't seem like the best solution

Comment: what kind of solution do you want?

Comment: If a way that doesn't ask you to configure anything and just works is not te best solution, i'm out of ideas.

Comment: are you saying that i can just move my plugin directory from vendor/plugins to under /app and it will just work?

Comment: Not your plugin directory, whatever you'd put inside your plugin's lib folder should be placed into "app/your_plugin_folder" and everything will be reloaded. Once you're done with coding your plugin, move it to the right folder (or just keep it inside app anyway if you don't plan to release it to the public).

Comment: what about when I want to develop a new feature I have to move it back out and then in again
whilst it works its not elegant and if I have multiple files i've got to manual keep track of what has changed
simply being able to tell rails to reload plugins or even everything in development mode would be ideal

Comment: The second option seems to work fine. I would recommend to put this "config.autoload_paths += %W{ #{config.root}/plugins }" into development config file (not application config)

Answer (score 0):

With https://github.com/ranmocy/guard-rails, it's super easy:

```
# Gemfile.local
gem 'guard-rails'


$ bundle
$ guard init rails


# Guardfile:
guard 'rails' do
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch(%r{^(config|plugins)/.*})
end


$ bundle exec guard
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution, for engines, works on Rails 2.3 but comes with one cavaet, it will load all files in the engine and parent app on every request which will make response times slower.

```
# lib/my_engine/engine.rb
if ENV['RELOAD_MYENGINE'] && Rails.env.development?
  config.to_prepare do
    Rails.logger.debug "RELOADING MY ENGINE"
    require_dependency MyEngine::Engine.root.join('lib', 'my_engine').to_s
  end

config.after_initialize do
  Rails.application.config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
end
```

Then start the server:

```
RELOAD_MYENGINE=1 rails server
```