# How can I automatically reload gem code on each request in development mode in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I am developing a Rails app where most of the code not specific to the app has been written inside of various gems, including some Rails engines and some 3rd party gems for which I am enhancing or fixing bugs.

```
gem 'mygem', path: File.expath_path('../../mygem', __FILE__)
```

Since a lot of the code in these gems is really part of the app, it's still changing frequently. I'd like to be able to utilize the Rails feature where code is reloaded on each request when in development (i.e. when `config.cache_classes` is false), but this is only done within the normal application structure by default.

How can I configure Rails to reload gem code on each request, just like with the app code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found through trial and error that several steps are required, with the help of `ActiveSupport`.

- Add `activesupport` as a dependency in the `.gemspec` files

  ```
  spec.add_dependency 'activesupport'
  ```
- Include ActiveSupport::Dependencies in the top-level module of your gem (this was the most elusive requirement)

  ```
  require 'bundler'; Bundler.setup
  require 'active_support/dependencies'

  module MyGem
    unloadable
    include ActiveSupport::Dependencies
  end

  require 'my_gem/version.rb'
  # etc...
  ```
- Set up your gem to use autoloading. You an either manually use ruby [autoload](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-autoload) declarations to map symbols into filenames, or use the Rails-style folder-structure-to-module-hierarchy rules (see [ActiveSupport #constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize))
- In each module and class in your gem, add `unloadable`.

  ```
  module MyModule
    unloadable
  end
  ```
- In each file that depends on a module or class from the gem, including in the gem itself, declare them at the top of each file using `require_dependency`. Look up the path of the gem as necessary to properly resolve the paths.

  ```
  require_dependency "#{Gem.loaded_specs['my_gem'].full_gem_path}/lib/my_gem/myclass"
  ```

If you get exceptions after modifying a file and making a request, check that you haven't missed a dependency.

For some interesting details see [this](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/) comprehensive post on Rails (and ruby) autoloading.

Comment: This answer was great but is a bit outdated now. The other answer is better for today.

Answer (score 3):

The solution that I used for Rails 6, with a dedicated Zeitwerk class loader and file checker :

- Add the gem to the Rails project using the `path:` option in `Gemfile`

  ```
  gem 'mygem', path: 'TODO'  # The root directory of the local gem
  ```
- In the `development.rb`, setup the classloader and the file watcher

  ```
  gem_path = 'TODO'  # The root directory of the local gem, the same used in Gemfile

  # Create a Zeitwerk class loader for each gem
  gem_lib_path = gem_path.join('lib').join(gem_path.basename)
  gem_loader = Zeitwerk::Registry.loader_for_gem(gem_lib_path)
  gem_loader.enable_reloading
  gem_loader.setup

  # Create a file watcher that will reload the gem classes when a file changes
  file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker.new(gem_path.glob('**/*')) do
    gem_loader.reload
  end

  # Plug it to Rails to be executed on each request
  Rails.application.reloaders << Class.new do 
    def initialize(file_watcher)
      @file_watcher = file_watcher
    end

    def updated?
      @file_watcher.execute_if_updated
    end
  end.new(file_watcher)
  ```

With this, on each request, the class loader will reload the gem classes if one of them has been modified.

For a detailed walkthrough, see my article [Embed a gem in a Rails project and enable autoreload](https://format-express.dev/blog/embed-a-gem-in-a-rails-project-and-enable-autoreload).

Comment: This is a great answer and the linked walkthrough is fantastic.