# How do you include a class from /lib into your code in app/controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a class sitting in /lib folder.
It's in a file called mailing.rb

And I would like to use this class in codes from app/controller.

How do i do this?

Comment: There is an answer to a similar question [Rails /lib modules and](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073076/rails-lib-modules-and) from @YehudaKatz.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rails 3 no longer automatically loads the files from `lib`.

In your `application.rb` file, you can add `lib` to your autoload_paths:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib"]
```

This way, your `mailer.rb` and all other files in `lib` will be available to the rest of your application.

Comment: Is an explicit `include myModule` statement required when `lib` is auto-loaded?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to add an initializer file with the require statement in it, for example if your lib file is /lib/some_module.rb you would need to create an initialiser file in /config/initializers/require_libs.rb...

```
# /config/initializers/require_libs.rb
require 'some_module'
```