# Is it possible to include modules in rake task and make its methods available for the task in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

In our `rails 3.2.12` app, there is a `rake task` created under `lib/tasks`. The `rake task` needs to call a method `find_config()` which resides in another rails module `authentify` (module is not under /lib/). Can we `include Authentify` in `rake task` and make method `find_config()` available to call in the rake task?

Here is what we would like to do in the `rake task`:

```
include Authentify
config = Authentify::find_config()
```

Thanks for comments.

Comment: why don't you create a  class to include the module and call the method using that class?

Comment: The method which needs to be called from rake test has to be called in module. The method is in module and is used by other code as well.

Comment: Did you actually try to do the `include Authentify` in a rake task to test it out? You're asking if it can be done. Just try it. In theory, anything the rails application can do from a Ruby standpoint, the rake task should also have access to... I think.

Comment: That's what I am asking about. Not sure if include is going to work in rake test. Haven't found an example yet. May give it a shot to see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: rake task returns error with include Authentify::AuthentifyUtility: uninitialized constant Authentify::AuthentifyUtility

Comment: After adding (:task_name) => :environment in rake task definition, the method is in the module is available to call from rake task. No need to include or require the module.

Answer (score 24):

```
 require 'modules/module_name'

 include ModuleName

 namespace :rake_name do

 desc "description of rake task"

  task example_task: :environment do

   result = ModuleName::method_name()


  end #end task


 end
```

This works for me. Since your Module is not in /lib you might have to edit how it is required. But it should work. Hope it helps.

Comment: Little tip. `require`'s working directory is `lib` so you should not include that in your path. For example, if you're importing a module in `lib/tasks/import/lookup.rb` then you would use `require 'tasks/import/lookup'`.

Answer (score 24):

**PLEASE PAY ATTENTION TO THIS AND SAVE SOME RANDOM HEADACHES!!** .
Don't include your module before your namespace:

```
include YourModule
namespace :your_name do
  desc 'Foo'
  task foo: :environment do
  end
end
```

or inside your namespace:

```
namespace :your_name do
  include YourModule

  desc 'Foo'
  task foo: :environment do
  end
end
```

as that will include your module **for the whole app** and it could bring you a lot of troubles (like me adding in the module some `:attr_accessor`s and breaking `factory-bot` functioning or other things it has happened in the past for this same reason).
The "no issues" way is inside of your task's scope:

```
namespace :your_name do
  desc 'Foo'
  task foo: :environment do
    include YourModule
  end
end
```

And yes, if you have multiple tasks, you should include in each of them:

```
namespace :your_name do
  desc 'Foo'
  task foo: :environment do
    include YourModule
  end

  desc 'Bar'
  task bar: :environment do
    include YourModule
  end
end
```

or simply call your method directly if you're only calling a method once in the task:

```
namespace :your_name do
  desc 'Foo'
  task foo: :environment do
    YourModule.your_method
  end

  desc 'Bar'
  task bar: :environment do
    YourModule.your_method
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

**How to require a Rails service/module in a Rake task?**

I had the same problem and manage to solve it by requiring the rails files inside the rake task.

I had a rake task named `give_something` defined in the file `lib/tasks/a_task.rake`.

Within that task I needed to call the function `give_something` from the module `AService` which lives in the file `app/services/a_service.rb`

The rake task was defined as follows:

```
namespace :a_namespace do
  desc "give something to a list of users"
  task give_something: :environment do

    AService.give_something(something, users)

  end
end
```

I was getting the error: `uninitialized constant AService`

To solve it I had to require the module not at the beginning of the file `a_task.rake`, but inside the rake task:

```
namespace :a_namespace do
  desc "give something to a list of users"
  task give_something: :environment do

    require 'services/a_service' # <-- HERE!
    AService.give_something(something, users)

  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

> In rails 5.x.x we can do as-

Module file exist her `app/lib/module/sub_module.rb` like-

```
module Module
  module SubModule

    def self.method(params1, params2)
      // code goes here...
    end

  end
end
```

and my rake_task presented here `/lib/tasks/my_tasks.rake` as-

```
namespace :my_tasks do
  desc "TODO"
  task :task_name => :environment do
    Module::SubModule.my_method(params1, params2)
  end
end
```

> Note:- the above task file presented in outer lib not in app/lib
>   Now run the task using following command-

```
rake my_tasks:task_name
```

from app directory not from `rails console`

That worked for me !!!

Comment: Do you actually call the module `Module`? I get an error saying `Module is not a module`.