# How do you include modules in rails schedule.rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, schedule, rake-task

I'm trying to require some modules I've written inside my schedule.rake file but am having trouble loading the file 'LoadError: cannot load such file -- app/models/concerns/sharedmethods'

What am I doing wrong? Is it the syntax?

Here is my schedule.rake

```
task :some_rake_task => :environment do       
    require 'app/bot/bot.rb'
    require 'app/models/concerns/sharedmethods'
    include SharedMethods

    #some rake function using methods in SharedMethods
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to include modules in rake task and make its methods available for the task in rails app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304110/is-it-possible-to-include-modules-in-rake-task-and-make-its-methods-available-fo)

Comment: @lcguida yes, it is the same problem but I'm still having trouble getting it to work.. maybe because directory is not correct? How do I find out which directory schedule.rake is in?

Answer (score 4):

It seemed like this solved the initial problem:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/bot/bot.rb"
```

But bot.rb has:

```
require "orderbot"
```

And I had to change all the follow require statements to:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/bot/orderbot.rb"
```