# How to include module class inside a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, include, rake, require

In rails 4 app, I am trying to create one rake task. I am trying to include a module feature for it but its not working.

Module file is (`/app/models/concerns/user/tags.rb`),

```
 module Concerns::User::Tags
   extend ActiveSupport::Concern
   ...
 end
```

Rakefile is (`/lib/tasks/keywords.rake`),

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/concerns/user/tags.rb"
include Concerns::User::Tags

namespace :keywords do
  desc 'Add data'
  task :add => :environment do
    puts "Adding"
  end
end
```

When I run this `bundle exec rake keywords:add -t` getting an error like,

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Concerns
/vagrant/app/models/concerns/user/tags.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/vagrant/lib/tasks/keywords.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

How can I solve this issue? Please help me.

Comment: its not the main problem but the require in the top rake file shouldn't be mandatory, it's supposed to be autoloaded. Can you share you develpoment.rb file, more specifically config,autoload_paths

Comment: In my `development.rb`, there is no `autoload_paths` stuff. In `application.rb`, `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` and `config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try moving the `include Concerns::User::Tags` inside the task block. If you need the module functionality in several tasks then yes include it in every task. You problem is essentially discussed here [Is it possible to include modules in rake task and make its methods available for the task in rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304110/is-it-possible-to-include-modules-in-rake-task-and-make-its-methods-available-fo)

Comment: @ShruthiR is spring running maybe? this is weird

Comment: `Spring is not running` is displayed.