# Ruby on Rails module include module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module

I want to include a module in a rails helper(is also a module).

**The helper is:**

```
module SportHelper 
  .....
end
```

**And the module is:**

```
module Formula
  def say()
    ....
  end
end
```

Now, I want to use the method `say` in `SportHelper`. What should I do?

**If I write like this:**

```
module SportHelper 
  def speak1()
    require 'formula'
    extend Formula
    say()
  end

  def speak2()
    require 'formula'
    extend Formula
    say()
  end
end
```

This will work, but I don't want to do so, I just want to add the methods on the helper module,not every methods.

Comment: Hi, which version of Ruby and Rails use your app?

Comment: why not every methods, and which are of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need just to include this module in your helper:

```
require 'formula'

module SportHelper
  include Formula

  def speak1
    say
  end

  def speak2
    say
  end
end
```

Maybe you don't need this line `require 'formula'`, if it's already in the load path. For check this you can inspect `$LOAD_PATH` variable. For more information see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073076/rails-lib-modules-and/1075595#1075595).

Basic difference between `extend` and `include` is that include is for adding methods to an instance of a class and extend is for adding class methods.

```
module Foo
  def foo
    puts 'heyyyyoooo!'
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

Bar.new.foo # heyyyyoooo!
Bar.foo # NoMethodError: undefined method ‘foo’ for Bar:Class

class Baz
  extend Foo
end

Baz.foo # heyyyyoooo!
Baz.new.foo # NoMethodError: undefined method ‘foo’ for #<Baz:0x1e708>
```

And if you use `extend` inside the object method, it will adding methods to an instance of a class, but they would be available only inside this one method.

Comment: Might want to mention the need for a `require` or why it's not required (e.g. due to autoload in Rails), given the OP's apparent confusion about require vs. include vs. extend.

Answer (score 1):

I think directly include should work

```
 module SportHelper 
      include SportHelper
      .........
      end
    end
```

I tested like below:

```
module A
       def test
          puts "aaaa"
       end
end

module B
    include A
    def test1
        test
    end
end

class C
    include B
end

c = C.new()
c.test1  #=> aaaa
```

It should work.